# How can I enable SSH login for this brand new user created on CentOS 7 machine?

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, centos-7

I am not a sysadmin (I am s software developer) and I am finding the following difficulty working on a Linux **CentOS 7** remote machine of a customer.

I am using MobaxTerm to connect to this machine. they provided me a **.ppk** file and a user.

The **.ppk** file contains something like this:

```
PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption: none
Comment: MY CUSTOMER KeyPair
Public-Lines: 6
.....................................................................
.....................................................................
.....................................................................
```

Importing this file I can log in into this machine without problem with the usere that they gived to me.

Then, after that I logged in with this provided user, I created a bran new root user using the following commands:

```
sudo adduser my_new_user
sudo passwd my_new_user
sudo usermod -aG wheel my_new_user
```

after that I have done this operation I can change user by:

```
su - my_new_user
```

it works fine and it seems that I have root access.

the problem is that now I can't access via SSH using this **my_new_user** user. If I try to prompt this username when I perform the log-in I obtain the following error message:

```
Server refused our key

No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
```

I suppose that this error depends by the fact that the imported **.ppk** file is related to the provided user and not for this brand new user (infact if I disable the **.ppk** import I obtain the same error also using the original provided user). I think that maybe I have to generate a new **.ppk** file also for this new user. Is it my reasoning correct? In case what is the correct procedure to generate this and have the chance to log in also with my brand new user?

Answer (score 1):

SSH keys are indeed user-specific, although the user assignment is done on the server and isn't a property of the key itself. The same key can be used to access multiple users/hosts but needs to be separately authorized for each user.

On Linux, the list of permitted keys is stored in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file within each user's home directory. It contains a list of *public* keys (in the OpenSSH format), with one key per line.

Loading your .ppk file in PuTTYgen (or even generating a new key) would directly show its public key in the OpenSSH format, which you can copy into your new user account's "authorized_keys" file.

(if you're editing the file with 'nano', make sure to disable its line-wrapping.)

---

Also, make sure your *customer* is actually okay with you creating new accounts on their server, since that's usually the responsibility of sysadmins and not of software developers.

Comment: In this case they give me the full controll of the situation (the classic nightmare scenario in which a DEV have to do also others job hehe). Just to well understand: if I take the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file from the original user provided and I put into the ~/.ssh/ folder of my brand new user it will work?

Comment: Yes, then it will begin accepting the same keys.

Comment: I tried to move in this folder but it still doens't log in with my brand new user. Do you think that I have to ask a reboot of the machine in order to apply this configuration or can I refresh configuration in somne way avoiding reboot?